# Binary Search Tree in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tree

I'm writing C++ for the first time and wanted to implement a BST. I come from writing C, so I tend to write code in that way. I'm trying to wrap my head around smart pointers, but can't seem to get them to work properly. This version of the code is without any smart pointers. Any suggestions?

The C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bst.h"

int main()
{
int i = 0;
BST<int> *tree = new BST<int>;

tree->addNode(new node<int>(6));
tree->addNode(new node<int>(5));
tree->addNode(new node<int>(2));
tree->addNode(new node<int>(5));
tree->addNode(new node<int>(7));
tree->addNode(new node<int>(8));

std::cout << "In order ";
tree->inOrderPrint(tree->getRoot());
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Pre order ";
tree->preOrderPrint(tree->getRoot());
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Post order ";
tree->postOrderPrint(tree->getRoot());
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Level order " << std::endl;
tree->levelOrderPrint(tree->getRoot());
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Minimum value " << tree->findMin(tree->getRoot())->getData();
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Maximum value " << tree->findMax(tree->getRoot())->getData();
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

std::cout << "Successor of 5: ";
if(node<int> *temp = tree->getSuccessor(tree->findNode(5)))
{
    std::cout << temp->getData() << std::endl;
} 
else
{
    std::cout << "None" << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "Successor of 8: ";
if(node<int> *temp = tree->getSuccessor(tree->findNode(8)))
{
    std::cout << temp->getData() << std::endl;
} 
else
{
    std::cout << "None" << std::endl;
} 

std::cout << "Predecessor of 7: ";
if(node<int> *temp = tree->getPredecessor(tree->findNode(7)))
{
    std::cout << temp->getData() << std::endl;
} 
else
{
    std::cout << "None" << std::endl << std::endl;
}

std::cout << "Predecessor of 2: ";
if(node<int> *temp = tree->getPredecessor(tree->findNode(2)))
{
    std::cout << temp->getData() << std::endl;
} 
else
{
    std::cout << "None" << std::endl << std::endl;
}    

std::cout << "Height: " << tree->getHeight(tree->getRoot()) << std::endl;

delete tree;

return 0;
}
```

The header file:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
                    __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
                    _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

template <typename T>
class node
{
    T data;
    node<T> *left;
    node<T> *right;
    node<T> *parent;

public:
    node(T value);
    ~node()  {};
    T getData();
    void updateLeft(node<T>* pointer);
    void updateRight(node<T>* pointer);
    void updateParent(node<T>* pointer);
    node<T>* getLeft();
    node<T>* getRight();
    node<T>* getParent();
};

template <typename T>
node<T> :: node(T value) : parent(NULL), left(NULL), right(NULL)
{
    data = value;
}

template <typename T>
T node<T> :: getData()
{
    return data;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T> :: updateLeft(node<T>* pointer)
{
    left = pointer;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T> :: updateRight(node<T>* pointer)
{
    right = pointer;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T> :: updateParent(node<T>* pointer)
{
    parent = pointer;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* node<T> :: getLeft()
{
    return left;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* node<T> :: getRight()
{
    return right;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* node<T> :: getParent()
{
    return parent;
}

template <typename T>
class BST
{
    node<T> *root;
    void removeNode(node<T> *delNode);
public:
    BST() : root(NULL) {}
    ~BST();
    node<T>* getRoot();
    node<T>* findMin(node<T> *current);
    node<T>* findMax(node<T> *current);
    node<T>* findNode(T key);
    node<T>* getSuccessor(node<T> *current);
    node<T>* getPredecessor(node<T> *current);
    bool addNode(node<T> *newNode);
    void inOrderPrint(node<T> *current);
    void preOrderPrint(node<T> *current);
    void postOrderPrint(node<T> *current);
    void levelOrderPrint(node<T> *current);
    void printLevel(node<T>* current, int level);
    int getHeight(node<T>* current);
};

template <typename T>
void BST<T> :: removeNode(node<T> *delNode)
{
    if(delNode)
    {
        removeNode(delNode->getLeft());
        removeNode(delNode->getRight());
        delete delNode;
    }
}

template <typename T>
BST<T> :: ~BST()
{
    removeNode(root);
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* BST<T> :: getRoot()
{
    return root;
}

template <typename T>
bool BST<T> :: addNode(node<T> *newNode)
{
    if(!root)
    {
        root = newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        node<T> *temp = root;
        node<T> *parent = NULL;

        while(temp)
        {
            parent = std::move(temp);
            if(newNode->getData() > temp->getData())
            {
                temp = temp->getRight();
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->getLeft();
            }
        }

        if(newNode->getData() > parent->getData())
        {
            parent->updateRight(newNode);
        }
        else
        {
            parent->updateLeft(newNode);
        }

        newNode->updateParent(parent);

    }
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* BST<T> :: findNode(T key)
{
    node<T> *temp = root;
    while(temp)
    {
        T data = temp->getData();
        if(data == key)
        {
            return temp;
        }

        else if(data > key)
        {
            temp = temp->getLeft();
        }

        else
        {
            temp = temp->getRight();
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

template <typename T>
void BST<T> :: inOrderPrint(node<T> *current)
{
    if(current)
    {
        inOrderPrint(current->getLeft());
        std::cout << current->getData() << " ";
        inOrderPrint(current->getRight());
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BST<T> :: preOrderPrint(node<T> *current)
{
    if(current)
    {
        std::cout << current->getData() << " ";
        inOrderPrint(current->getLeft());
        inOrderPrint(current->getRight());
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BST<T> :: postOrderPrint(node<T> *current)
{
    if(current)
    {
        inOrderPrint(current->getLeft());
        inOrderPrint(current->getRight());
        std::cout << current->getData() << " ";
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BST<T> :: printLevel(node<T>* current, int level)
{
    if(current)
    {
        if(level == 0)
        {
            std::cout << current->getData() << " ";
        }
        else
        {
            printLevel(current->getLeft(), level-1);
            printLevel(current->getRight(), level-1);
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BST<T> :: levelOrderPrint(node<T> *current)
{
    int height = getHeight(current);
    for(int level = 0; level < height; level++)
    {
        printLevel(current, level);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* BST<T> :: findMin(node<T> *current)
{
    node<T> *temp = current;
    node<T> *prev;
    while(temp)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->getLeft();
    }

    return prev;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* BST<T> :: findMax(node<T> *current)
{
    node<T> *temp = root;
    node<T> *prev;
    while(temp)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->getRight();
    }

    return prev;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* BST<T> :: getSuccessor(node<T> *current)
{
    if(current->getRight())
    {
        return findMin(current->getRight());
    }

    node<T> *parent = current->getParent();
    while(parent && current == parent->getRight())
    {
        current = parent;
        parent = parent->getParent();
    }

    return parent;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* BST<T> :: getPredecessor(node<T> *current)
{
    if(current->getLeft())
    {
        return findMax(current->getLeft());
    }

    node<T> *parent = current->getParent();
    while(parent && current == parent->getLeft())
    {
        current = parent;
        parent = parent->getParent();
    }

    return parent;
}

template <typename T>
int BST<T> :: getHeight(node<T> *current)
{
    int max = 0;
    if(!current)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    max = MAX(getHeight(current->getLeft()), getHeight(current->getRight()));
    return (1 + max);
}
```

Comment: We cannot assist with adding smart pointers, but we can review everything else (if it all works).

Comment: Everything works. Just wanted to know if I'm following best practices.

Comment: Can you use / your compiler supports **C++11**?

Comment: Yes, I can use C++11.

Comment: This will be a fun review. I cannot do it now, but I'll do it in 8ish hours if it has not been done by then.

Answer (score 3):

No complete review, but some points to mention (in no specific order). When I speak in imperatives, consider them always as suggestions:

---

#### General things:

- Don't use this macro:

  ```
      #define MAX(a, b) ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
              __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
              _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
  ```

  Rather, use the `std::max` function template defined in the `algorithm` header:

  ```
      std::max(a,b);
  ```
- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

---

#### Smart pointers:

Regarding the design of your `node` class, here are two suggestions, one using `std::unique_ptr` the other `std::shared_ptr`.

**Using std::unique_ptr:**

First, the `unique_ptr` alternative. For this, you can use a `node` class as follows:

```
    template <typename T>
    class node
    {
        T data;
        node *parent; 
        // or: 
        // node * const parent; 
        std::unique_ptr<node> right;
        std::unique_ptr<node> left;
    }
```

Note that I didn't use `node<T>` but rather only `node` inside the class. This is because inside a class template, the [class name refers to its current instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17287778/2412846).

- Choice of `left` and `right`:

  The child nodes `left` and `right` now are `unique_ptr`'s, which states that the `node` exclusively owns its childs. This is convenient, because, say, when you remove the node from the tree, you usually want all child and grand-child nodes below that erased node to disappear as well. By using `std::unique_ptr`, you get this for free. Once more, this is the advantage in following the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) principle: the class manage it's memory ressources itself, so you don't have to care for that manually (as you do via the function `removeNode`).  When you use raw pointers instead, this will become much more difficult and error-prone.
- Choice of `parent`:

  On the other hand, `parent` is chosen as a raw pointer with the intention to act solely as an observer. It relies on the fact that the `node` object of which it is a member is also correctly managed by a `unique_ptr`. So it will always point to a valid object. Note that you should never do some memory-related operations using parent.

  As it is also unlikely that child nodes have to change its parent (and since strictly speaking it is forbidden without also changing the managing `unique_ptr`), you can also declare the raw pointer as `const` by `node * const parent;`. Note that the `const` here comes after the `*` which means the pointer itself is const (not the object it points to). But changing `parent` (in a reasonable way) might also be needed in in rare occasions, so it is maybe too restrictive to generally suggest this.
- Copying, assignment, etc.

  Note that you can't copy the tree with nodes as defined above (at least you won't get it for free, i.e. the copy constructor is not automatically generated by the compiler), which is because `std::unique_ptr`'s copy constructor is `delete`'d. So there will always exist only one valid tree (which is usually passed by reference). If you want copies, you can either implement a deep copy, by which you get a completely new tree (--if you change the copy, the original tree will not change). Or you can return an `observer_node` class which resembles yours above (in which you should *never* do any memory-related operations such as `delete`):

  ```
  template <typename T>
  class observer_node
  {
      T data;
      node<T> *left;
      node<T> *right;
      node<T> *parent;
  };
  ```

  But I doubt that I really would do this. The copied-node is read-only (with regard to the topology, i.e. you cannot add or remove nodes) and, in order to work, it poses severe restrictions on the original tree. For instance, one cannot reduce the number of nodes, as then the copied-node will contain a dangling pointer.

  For the assignment-- which is usually implemented via the copy-and-swap idiom and thus in terms of the copy constructor -- similar things hold.

  So, if you really want to be able to do pointer-copying, you should consider the next alternative.

---

**Using std::shared_ptr:**

Here the class looks like this:

```
    template <typename T>
    class node : public std::enable_shared_from_this<node<T> >
    {
        T data;
        node *parent;
        // or:
        // std::weak_ptr<node> parent
        std::shared_ptr<node> right;
        std::shared_ptr<node> left;
    }
```

- Choice of `left` and `right`.

  Now, the child node pointers are `shared_ptr`. They do not exclusively own the object they point to.
- Copying, etc:

  The implications are best worked out by considering the copy behaviour (for whose accomplishment you will get compiler-generated copy, assignment, etc. constructors). Now, copying works as following: a new tree of nodes is generated which point to the same memory locations on the heap. In the copied tree, you can safely change the topology of the tree, i.e. add or remove nodes -- the `shared_ptr` will always take care that the pointed-to objects survive as long as at least one node is pointing to them. You must be careful, though, when you change the member `data` in the copied tree, as this will change also the value in the original tree.
- Choice of `parent`

  `parent` again can be chosen as an only-observing raw pointer. The rationale is the same way as before: it relies on the fact that the parent node is managed by another `shared_ptr` and thus will always exist.

  If you wanted to be sure about that, you could also use a `weak_ptr` here, but I don't think it is necessary.

---

Oh man, my reviews always get so long ... hope it is helpful and that you even managed to get here.

Comment: One might want to be able to split a tree in two or merge two trees into a larger one. Then the parent pointer would need updating.

Comment: With `std::shared_ptr` I would use `std::enable_shared_from_this` for nodes. That way a node an return a shared pointer to itself to return a subtree without having to go through the parent. This avoids having to special case the root and checking if you need the left or right child.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: yes, deriving from `std::enable_shared_from_this` is a reasonable thing, added this. I had the same feeling about the `parent` pointer, so I recommended it to be non-const in general.

Comment: Small error, `std::max` is actually defined by [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) not by `<cmath>` as you have stated.

Comment: @glampert: right, thanks for correction. This is something I quite often stumbled upon... and were always surprised. Corrected.

Comment: That's great, thanks! I should try to incorporate smart pointers into my design.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you read the [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/70926/47624) already.

- Your `MAX` macro is inefficient because it copies its arguments. `std::max` does not have that problem. Also `decltype` is a portable version of `__typeof__` and in this case you could have used `auto` instead.
- ```
  int main(){
      BST<int> *tree = new BST<int>;
      ...
      delete tree;
  }
  ```

  Putting variables on the stack makes managing memory easier than with smart pointers:

  ```
  int main(){
      BST<int> tree;
      ...
  }
  ```

  Exception safety, less code and less awkward syntax are an additional bonus.
- In `main` you define `int i;` but never use it. Your compiler should warn you about that. Define variables as late as possible instead of defining all variables at the beginning of a function.
- As a user of your class I do not care about `node`s. If I have to handle `node`s I may as well write my own tree instead of using yours. `node` is an implementation detail.

  ```
  class BST{
      struct Node{
          T data;
          ...
      };
  public:
      ...
  };
  ```

  Now `Node` is `private` and not accessible for users. Instead of `bool addNode(node<T> *newNode);` we now have `void insert(const T &t);` and `void insert(T &&t);`. If the `&&` confuses you read about [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics). Internally it does basically the same thing as `addNode` did before. The member functions you have become `private` and we add new member functions:

  ```
  template <class T>
  class BST{
      ...
  public:
      const T &min() const;
      const T &max() const;
      bool contains(const T &key) const;
      void inOrderPrint() const;
      void preOrderPrint() const;
      void postOrderPrint() const;
      void levelOrderPrint() const;
      int getHeight() const;
      void remove(const T &t);
      ...
  };
  ```

  Those functions also do what they did before, just more convenient to use.
- ```
  BST<int> *tree = new BST<int>;
  tree->addNode(new node<int>(6));
  tree->addNode(new node<int>(5));
  tree->addNode(new node<int>(2));
  tree->addNode(new node<int>(5));
  tree->addNode(new node<int>(7));
  tree->addNode(new node<int>(8));
  ```

  This sucks. You want it to look something like this:

  ```
  BST<int> tree = { 6, 5, 2, 5, 7, 8 };
  ```

  To do that you add a constructor that takes an `initializer_list` and inserts all the elements into the tree:

  ```
  BST(const std::initializer_list<T> &il){
      for (auto &e : il)
          insert(e);
  }
  BST(std::initializer_list<T> &&il){
      for (auto &e : il)
          insert(std::move(e));
  }
  ```

  You need to `#include <initializer_list>` for this to work.
- I would add copy assignment operators and assignment operators for `initializer_list`:

  ```
  BST &operator =(BST &&other);
  BST &operator =(const BST &other);
  BST &operator =(std::initializer_list<T> &&il);
  BST &operator =(const std::initializer_list<T> &il);
  ```
- Consider implementing iterators. An iterator is similar to a pointer, you get the beginning with `auto it = bst.begin();` and the next element with `++it;`. When `it == bst.end();` you are done iterating. The point is that you can separate algorithms such as `inOrderPrint` and containers such as `BST`. Instead of implementing `n` algorithms for `m` containers with a total of `n * m` implementations you need only `n + m` implementations if you use iterators and all the neat algorithms such as `std::find_if` and `std::accumulate` will work on your `BST`. It is quite a bit of work to implement iterators, especially since you will probably need to implement 3 kinds for in-order, pre-order and post-order. Once you have those iterators and add support for streams your tree becomes fun to work with:

  ```
  std::ifstream fin("myTree.txt");
  BST<int> bst;
  fin >> bst; //read tree from file
  std::cout << bst; //print tree
  //dumping tree to disk
  std::ofstream fout("preordertree.txt");
  for (auto it = bst.preOrderBegin(); it != bst.preOrderEnd(); ++it)
      fout << *it << '\n';
  ```

When you get bored adding features to your `BST` take a close look at `std::set` and `std::vector` + `std::sort` + `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: Nice complimentary review, +1. Regarding the `initializer_list` stuff: although it is a good thing in general, I think that `tree = { 6, 5, 2, 5, 7, 8 }` is not really intuitive: in order to know the distribution of values to the nodes I need to know powers of two. There might be applications where you simply insert somewhere all values you need, but in others this distribution matters, and then the initializer_list is error-prone ... I'm indecisive whether I would add it, with a slight tendency to yes (--lastly we do C++ and users have to know what they do ;-)). Just wanted to mention that.

Comment: Next, can you comment what you mean exactly by inOrder, preOrder and postOrder iterators? What exactly does `++` for them? Basically, I can think of several alternatives to traverse the tree, with "layer-by-layer from left-to-right" being probably the easiest to understand. Which one did you mean?

Comment: @davidhigh I did not understand the power of two part. When iterating through values the values come in some order, usually in sequential order for `vector`-like containers or from lowest to highest for `set`-like containers. The question contained code for `inOrderPrint`, `preOrderPrint`, `postOrderPrint` and `levelOrderPrint` which one could mimic with different iterator types. Operator ++ would then get the next element based on the order encoded in its type.

Comment: the power-of-two part was meant like this: `tree = {1}` means there is only the root node with a value of `1`. `tree = {1,2,3}` means there are further left and right childs of the root node. `tree = {1,2}` means only `left` is assigned (--first question: is this really desired? often either none or both children are assigned). When I now want to assign,say, `7` to the `root->left->left->right` node, I must think a while where to insert a `7` in the `initializer_list`.

Comment: this touches also my other question about iterators: in order to use an `initializer_list`, one needs an intuitive way to traverse the storage scheme (--the same holds for an iterator). So, does `tree={1,2,3}` means `root, root->left, root->right` are assigned, or does it mean `root, root->left, root->left->left`, or something completely different? These questions must be answered in order to use both concepts (iterators and initializer_lists) unambiguously.

Comment: @davidhigh I thought the tree will balance itself when values are inserted. The order of the values in the initializer list should therefore have no significant influence on the tree, so you never need to think about the order. Also in my model you would never assign to `root->left->left->right`, you just insert the value into the tree which somehow handles node assignments internally. Maybe `insert` is just a `vector.push_back()` + `sort(vector)` and there is no such thing as `root`, `right` and `left`.

Comment: ok, I see we have different requirements on binary trees. I mainly come from the statistics side using methods such as CART where the topology matters. Yours seem to me more informatics-driven. Still I think that *automatic* balancing is a bit too much of an assumption for a general tree.